# For any ordinal, does it's cardinality equal its least upper bound

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Can you make the claim that for any ordinal, its cardinality equals it's least upper bound.

This is motivated by:

> > $\bigcup\omega+1=\omega$ and $|\omega+1|=\omega$

where $\bigcup\omega+1$ is also the $\text{sup}(\omega+1)$

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is $\bigcup (\omega^2) ?$

Comment: Maybe I'm correct to say $|\omega^2|=\omega$ (or $\aleph_0$), but I'm stuck on the union. Could I have a hint?

Comment: In any case it is larger than $\omega$ as an ordinal, so they are not equal.

Comment: Well, I'm still pondering this. If $\omega^2=\omega\cdot\omega$ then is it not $\omega$ copies of $\omega$? And if $\bigcup S$ is the members of the members of $S$ and if $\{x, x\}=\{x\}$, then what else is there in $\bigcup \omega^2$ than $\omega$? Thanks,

Comment: @Andrew:  For example, $\omega+1 $ is in $\bigcup \omega^2$, as is $\omega2, \omega7+8$ and others.  In fact the union of any limit ordinal is the ordinal itself.

Answer (score 0):

If $+$ denotes ordinal arithmetic, then $\cup\omega + 1$ is  already not $\omega$ but its successor (since $\cup\omega = \omega$).

If $+$ denotes something else, please tell us what you mean by it

Comment: It would have been a comment if I had known you made a typo.  But I can't take ownership for not reading your mind.  That's on you to express yourself clearly.

Comment: It's not a typo. I just had to spell it out for you.

Comment: Next you're going to tell me 1+2×2 is 6.  LOL

Comment: No I don't think so.  People view poorly stated questions briefly and move on all the time.

Comment: You might take a look at the paragraph following Prop. 12 on page 4 of this http://www.math.cmu.edu/~clintonc/s2018/ordinals.pdf.